# Can't upload image on LinkedIn using Selenium / wired text pops (data-artdeco-is-focused="true")

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am making a program that will automatically post image on LinkedIn.

It is only able to click on the 'Photo', after that it does't click on anything.

I found that when I try to select the 'select images to share' button, it does't work.

So, I **manually clicked on 'select images to share' button and in the second line of the HTML code, this popped from nowhere** :

```
data-artdeco-is-focused="true"
```

And, when I try to copy it by clicking on HTML code on the browser, it hides the code.

[image]

This is the HTML code: *(<data-artdeco-is-focused="true"> appeared in the end of second line of the HTML code below)*

```
<div class="image-sharing-detour-container">
    <input id="image-sharing-detour-container__file-input" class="image-sharing-detour-container__media-button visually-hidden" name="file" multiple="" filecountlimit="9" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" type="file">
    <div class="image-sharing-detour-container__upload-media-button">
      <label for="image-sharing-detour-container__file-input" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary">
        Select images to share
      </label>
    </div>
<!---->    <div class="share-box-footer ">
  <div class="share-box-footer__main-actions">
      <button id="ember421" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view" type="button"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Cancel
</span></button>
          <button disabled="" id="ember422" class="ml2 artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary artdeco-button--disabled ember-view" type="button"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Done
</span></button>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my python code so far;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep as slp


#open browser & visit linkedin
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/....../chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/')


#enter user/pass & click submit
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_key']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_password']")))

username.clear()
username.send_keys("user@gmail.com")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("mypasswordhere")

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()


#go to company page
checkpoint = driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/company/1234567/admin/')


#click on photo and add an image
addphoto = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Add a photo']"))
```

(Edit: this is the *//button[@aria-label='Add a photo']* in th HTML code)

[image]

Comment: I could not find `//button[@aria-label='Add a photo']` on the page

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @cruisepandey. It's actually the 'Photo' button below the 'Start a post' text on home page. I added the photo in the end of my question.